# Custom DataTemplate - Control doesn't occupy full grid column width

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I am bit confused about layout of my custom datatemplate in a listbox.
Problem is that each of the ListBoxItem doesn't occupy the full row width.

Here is the DataTemplate for the ListBox:

```
<Window x:Class="NewPropertyGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NewPropertyGrid"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PropertyListTemplate">
            <Grid Background="Yellow">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PropType,Converter={local:PropTypeToString}}"
                                   Margin="1"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Background="LightGray"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   />

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="="
                                   Margin="1"
                                   Background="LightGray"
                                   Foreground="Black"
                                   />

                <ContentControl Grid.Column = "2"
                                Content = "{Binding Editor}"
                                HorizontalAlignment = "Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment = "{Binding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox x:Name="lv" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyListTemplate}" Background="Green" />
</Window>
```

As you see, there are 3 columns in the Grid. The third one is supposed to be `Editor` (FrameworkElement), decided via code behind. Here is the class data structure which acts as the source of information:

```
namespace NewPropertyGrid {
    public enum PropType { Name, Age, Surname };

    public class PropItem {
        public PropType PropType { get; set; }

        object _Value = null;
        internal object Value {
            get {
                return _Value;
            }
            set {
                _Value = value;
                DetectEditor();
            }
        }

        public FrameworkElement Editor { get; set; }

        public void DetectEditor() {
            var t = Value.GetType();
            if (t == typeof(string)) {
                var txt = new TextBox();
                txt.Text = Value as string;
                Editor = txt;
            }
            else if (t.IsArray) {
                var cmb = new ComboBox();
                cmb.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable)Value;
                if (cmb.Items.Count > 0)
                    cmb.SelectedIndex = 0;
                Editor = cmb;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I load data in the listbox,

```
namespace NewPropertyGrid {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += (s, e) => {
                var list = new List<PropItem>();
                list.Add(new PropItem() {
                PropType = global::NewPropertyGrid.PropType.Name,
                Value = "Tester"
                });
                list.Add(new PropItem() {
                PropType = global::NewPropertyGrid.PropType.Surname,
                Value = new string[] { "X", "Y", "Z" }
                });

                lv.ItemsSource = list;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I see that the frameworkelement `Editor` doesn't use the full row width as dictated by the third column of the Grid.

This is how the row looks like (screenshot of [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)). Notice that the textbox with text 'Tester' is not using the full width of the 3rd column. [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) tells me that the `ContentPresenter` in ListBoxItem default template, is not using the full width, even though *Bd* border does (notice ActualWidth of *Bd*)!
[image: This is how the row looks like (screenshot of Snoop)]

How can I change the DataTemplate so that the `Editor` uses the full column width?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` for your `ListBoxItem`. It can be done in `ItemContainerStyle`.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lv" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PropertyListTemplate}"
         Background="Green">
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Crap! And I wasted 4 hours trying to figure out why it was not working. WPF guys should be sued for not setting default value of "HorizontalContentAlignment" as "Stretch". :-/